# Can a Medicae test for First Aid be retried after failure?

Tags: skills, dark-heresy-2e

Can a Medicae test for First Aid be retried after failure?  Specifically, within the next 24 hours.

The reason I ask is because of the following quote within the First Aid description.

> A given individual can only be treated with first aid once every 24 hours, and only so long as he is not also undergoing extended care.

I understand that if the Medicae test for First Aid succeeds, then the individual cannot be treated again until 24 hours pass.  However, does a failed Medicae test for First Aid consider the individual treated, but the treatment failed to have a positive effect?  Or is a failed Medicae test for First Aid a failure to provide treatment, thus the individual remains untreated until a successful Medicae test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: No - without spending a Fate Point or having some other mechanic to trigger a re-roll, a PC can't attempt another First-Aid Medicae test after failing on the same patient for 24 hours.

Longer Answer: A failed Medicae test for First-Aid would consider the patient treated but that no positive result occurred. I feel that if failing the Medicae test just means you provided no aid at all, that you could just try again immediately.

I think an important point to make here is that for other kinds of Medicae tests (as well as most other tests in general in Dark Heresy), failure carries with it the possibility of outrageous bodily harm and spiritual damnation. Failing an Extended Care Medicae test has the potential to kill every patient you have! If you apply the Extended Care reasoning to the First-Aid (both found in 2e-Core on page 109), you have the possibility of killing your patient for extreme failures. Aren't there cases of Good Samaritans trying to help someone and accidentally killing them? That's what Deadly First Aid fail rolls are.

Comment: Not seeing how your final point factors in.  This is true for all skills that have gear to boost them.  Therefore I don't see how it supports or proves anything.  I do mostly agree with the rest of your reasoning though.

Comment: I've since come across this bit in the Trying Again subsection of the Skills chapter, _"Where appropriate, a skill entry lists whether it can be attempted more than once, and gives suggestions for the consequences of failure."_  Which I now realize is exactly what the paragraph I originally quoted is doing, it listed the condition on how often First Aid can be attempted. And an attempt doesn't matter in regards to success or failure, it's simply an attempt at the test. Thus I believe this answer is correct, even if it has a point that doesn't support the answer.

Comment: Agreed the final point was irrelevant - removed it. Also, thanks for referencing the Trying Again subsection, as I didn't recall that one myself.